# Unpacking the definition of a likelihood function

Tags: statistics

I am learning stats. My book says let $X_{i}, ..., X_{n}$ be IID with PDF $f(x;\theta)$. It then defines a likelihood function as

$$\displaystyle L_{n}(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^nf(x;\theta)$$

I think that this means to multiply the sums of the pdf $f(x;\theta)$ for all of the iid random variables.

I am confused by this because it seems like you need an interval to get a non zero value from a pdf. A pdf will equal zero at any given point because the probability will be zero. So how can the pdf have a value without lower and upper bound parameters? Are these somehow implied? How can I unpack this likelihood function?

Comment: "A pdf will equal zero at one exact point." No. (Suppose a X is gaussian, then the pdf is non-zero at all points). You are perhaps confusing this with the "probability that X equals (some point)" -  which is indeed zero - but that's irrelevant. The likelihood is NOT a probability. Furthermore, your definition lacks an index for the product, it should be $f(x_i;\theta)$ instead.

Comment: @leonbloy sorry. that was unclear. I was trying to say "probability that X equals (some point)." How can f(x:theta) equal any value without bounds?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725843/likelihood-function-for-continuous-densities

Answer (score 2):

Algebraically, the only difference between a **density** and a **likelihood** is that a density integrates to $1$ over its support.  A density is a likelihood, but a likelihood is not always a density.

Semantically, a likelihood is a function of the parameters of the model for some observed data.  A density is a function of the observations for some fixed (but not necessarily known) parameters.

Here is a concrete example.  Suppose a company makes a particular type of electronic component in a factory, and the company models the lifetime of a given component with an exponentially distributed random variable $X$ with some unknown mean $\mu$.  The company decides to estimate $\mu$ from a random sample of components.

First, the company tests a sample of size $n$, and labels their lifetimes as the ordered $n$-tuple $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$.  Assuming that these are independent and identically distributed from $X$, we then characterize the **joint density** of this set of observations as $$f(\boldsymbol x \mid \mu) = f(x_1 \mid \mu) f(x_2 \mid \mu) \cdots f (x_n \mid \mu) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\mu} e^{-x_i/\mu}.$$  This expression is not a probability in itself, as lifetimes are continuously distributed and thus the exact probability of observing this particular outcome is zero; but it captures in some sense the relative *tendency* for such an outcome to occur, with higher values representing greater possibility.

But this is precisely the same thing as a *likelihood*:  the only difference is that the joint density has been normalized over the space of all possible outcomes, so that the total (integral) equals 1.  So whereas the density is regarded as a function of the sample $\boldsymbol x$ for some fixed (but unknown) $\mu$, the likelihood is regarded as a function of $\mu$ for some sample $\boldsymbol x$:  $$L(\mu \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto f(\boldsymbol x \mid \mu) = \begin{cases} \mu^{-n} \exp(- n \bar x /\mu), & \mu > 0 \\ 0 & \mu \le 0, \end{cases}$$ where I have used $\bar x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ to represent the sample mean, and I have evaluated the product and qualified the range of $\mu$ for which the a proper density (and therefore a proper likelihood) exists.

This likelihood therefore also quantifies how likely the true mean is to be a particular value for a given sample:  if $L(\mu_0 \mid \boldsymbol x) < L(\mu_1 \mid \boldsymbol x)$, then in some sense, $\mu_1$ is a more *plausible* value for $\mu$ given the observed lifetimes under the conditions of the model we imposed.  Hence it makes sense to talk about **maximizing** the likelihood, and **estimating** the mean lifetime $\mu$ as that value which maximizes the likelihood, which we call the **maximum likelihood estimator**.  This is done by calculus, and it is a simple exercise to show that $L$ is maximized when $$\mu = \hat\mu = \bar x,$$ which is in agreement with our intuition:  the "most likely" mean lifetime of the **population** of components is equal to the **sample mean**.

From here, we can also compute the variance of this estimator; e.g., $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat\mu] = \frac{\mu^2}{n},$$ which of course is a function of the true mean $\mu$:  the larger the true mean lifetime, the more variance you would expect to see in the sample mean.  It also tells us that the variance of the sample mean decreases with increasing sample size--the more components you test, the more reliable your estimate.  We can even talk about the **estimated variance of the sample mean**:  $$\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}[\hat\mu] = \frac{\bar x^2}{n},$$ which is not a function of the parameter $\mu$--we *estimated* it using the data, letting the company create an interval estimate and give a "margin of error" for the true mean lifetime, rather than just a point estimate of the true mean lifetime.